# EF 6 with ODP.Net Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, How to Use Non-Capital Letter for Class Properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, oracle-manageddataaccess

I am using the EF 6 with ODP.Net `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` for my ASP.Net MVC Web application.

I have the following `Model` called `Employee` (in `Model\Employee.cs` file):

```
[Table("TBLEMPLOYEE")]
public class Employee {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeType { get; set; }
    public double? AnnualSalary { get; set; }
    public double? HourlyPay { get; set; }
    public double? HoursWorked { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

As well as `EmployeeContext.cs`

```
public class EmployeeContext : DbContext {
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("myschema");
    }
}
```

Then, in my `EmployeeController.cs`, I use the `Employee` and the `EmployeeContext` like this:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id = 1) {
    try {
        EmployeeContext employeeContext = new EmployeeContext();
        employeeContext.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
        Employee employee = employeeContext.Employees.Single(x => x.ID == id);
        return View(employee);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return View(e);
    }
}
```

When I get the following Inner exception error:

> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-00904: "Extent1"."Id": invalid identifier

The exception error occurs in:

```
Employee employee = employeeContext.Employees.Single(x => x.ID == id);
```

As I debug further by using my Debug output console, I noticed that the EF generates the following SQL query to fetch the data:

```
SELECT 
"Extent1"."Id" AS "Id", 
"Extent1"."Name" AS "Name", 
"Extent1"."Gender" AS "Gender", 
"Extent1"."DateOfBirth" AS "DateOfBirth", 
"Extent1"."EmployeeType" AS "EmployeeType", 
"Extent1"."AnnualSalary" AS "AnnualSalary", 
"Extent1"."HourlyPay" AS "HourlyPay", 
"Extent1"."HoursWorked" AS "HoursWorked", 
"Extent1"."City" AS "City"
FROM "MYSCHEMA"."TBLEMPLOYEE" "Extent1"
WHERE ("Extent1"."Id" = :p__linq__0) AND (ROWNUM <= (2) )
```

And as I do some more research, I understand that due to the present of the quotation marks `" "` in the SQL query column names (such as `."Id"`, `".EmployeeType"`, `".HourlyPay"` and so on), the query cannot find matching Column names as the Oracle Data Table column name is all represented in capital letters (that is: `."ID"`, `".EMPLOYEETYPE"`, `".HOURLYPAY"` and so on).

Now, when I changed the class definition into something like this:

```
[Table("TBLEMPLOYEE")]
public class Employee {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string GENDER { get; set; }
    public DateTime DATEOFBIRTH { get; set; }
    public int EMPLOYEETYPE { get; set; }
    public double? ANNUALSALARY { get; set; }
    public double? HOURLYPAY { get; set; }
    public double? HOURSWORKED { get; set; }
    public string CITY { get; set; }
}
```

It works perfectly fine. *But I do not want that*.

As a typical C# coder, I found it *quite unusual* to have all capital letters for class fields/properties.

My question is, is there any way to retain the class properties using combination of capital and small letters yet, only for querying, generated capitalized letters version of those properties?

Again, I use EF `6.0.0.0` and ODP.Net `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` version `4.121.2.0` and `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework` version `6.121.2.0` if those things matter.

Comment: That's interesting issue. I'm wondering why your table column names are uppercased at the first place. Aren't you using Code First migrations? According to [this post](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/CodeFirst/index.html) the column names should be exactly as you define them inside the entity classes.

Comment: @IvanStoev I created my tables using Toad for Oracle. Perhaps, it is part of the reason.

Comment: I see. The accepted answer works, but is too annoying. You may find this post [How to map a column to uppercase in .NET 4.5 C# EF6 using both Oracle and SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418522/how-to-map-a-column-to-uppercase-in-net-4-5-c-sharp-ef6-using-both-oracle-and-s), especially the [Gert Arnold](http://stackoverflow.com/users/861716/gert-arnold)'s answer.

Comment: @IvanStoev hi, thanks for the link! I found it to be useful! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Column` data attribute on each property to specify the mapped column name to use when the table is created, much the same as the `Table` attribute. Then, your actual property names can be correctly formatted:

```
[Table("TBLEMPLOYEE")]
public class Employee {
    [Column("ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("NAME")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    etc...
}
```

More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#TableColumn

You can also use the fluent API in your `DbContext` to specify a column name mapping:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //Configure Column
    modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
                .Property(p => p.Id)
                .HasColumnName("ID");

    modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
                .Property(p => p.Name)
                .HasColumnName("NAME");
}
```

Reference: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-property-mappings-using-fluent-api.aspx

Comment: Can this be code-generated, or do you have to hand-code all of these attributes?

Comment: @RobertHarvey of course you can generate it, it depends on how you're generating but it should be fairly straight forward to add it into the template.

Comment: Ah, so modify the T4 template to include the attributes.  Seems reasonable.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, yes. I don't use T4 templates myself, but I'd imagine it's the same as what you're doing for the table name.

Comment: @RobertHarvey ,don't forget though, this being a code-first solution, that you only need to do this once during setup of the DTOs and then you can ignore it.

Comment: @Steve thanks, your solution indeed is working well. You have my upvote. However, this may require us to make `[Column]` decorator for every property in every class. Though this may be argued to be declared but once, things may become more troublesome when we refractor any of them in the middle of development. Do you happen to know any more automatic way to do it?

Comment: @Ian other than Robert's suggestion of code generation, you could also use the fluent API (I've edited my answer with an example). Of course this really just moves your problem to a different place. I'm not sure of any other way that's more automatic.

Comment: @Steve I see... Too bad... :( I was hoping there is more automatic way to do this. Nevertheless, thanks for your prompt answer. If that be the only way, then I will just have to take that pain.

Answer (score 3):

A more automated (easier) way would be to utilize EF [Custom Code First Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819164.aspx) feature.

First you'll need a simple class like this

```
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm;

public class UppercaseColumnNameConvention : IStoreModelConvention<EdmProperty>
{
    public void Apply(EdmProperty item, DbModel model)
    {
        item.Name = item.Name.ToUpper();
    }
}
```

then in your context class

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add<UppercaseColumnNameConvention>();
    // ...
}
```

and you are done.

Comment: Hi Ivan, thanks for your re-direction yesterday. I updated my code with the solution from Gert Arnold. And it worked fine. You got my upvote. ;)

Comment: Hi @Ian, I decided to post this because it runs after applying other configuration stuff like `Column` attributes etc., so it works with the actual column names and is enforcing the uppercasing, while the Gert solution is working with CLR property names and can be overridden by other configuration players (I think he mentioned that). Cheers!

Comment: ah, I see... you are saying that this solution is more robust towards multiple players involved (aren't you? Or your case are also suspected to overriden - since both use `OnModelCreating`?). In my case, the only player would be me. :) Nevertheless, you certainly provide an alternative-automated solution for whoever needs additional robustness feature. ;)

Comment: You got me right. By player I meant attributes, fluent configurations etc. Actually seem to be quite powerful - all the EF internal conventions are implemented with such classes. Anyway, I'm learning myself too, and as mentioned in the first comment, it's quite interesting :)

Comment: seems like you still need `modelBuilder.Types().Configure(c => c.ToTable(c.ClrType.Name.ToUpper(), "USER"));` for capital table names, at least for oracle

Comment: and anyway it tries to create many-to-many tables like this: `CreateTable(                "USER.Test2Test1"...`

Comment: @Toolkit The question was for column names. For table names you could try another one like `public class UppercaseTableNameConvention : IStoreModelConvention<EntityType>
 {
  public void Apply(EntityType item, DbModel model)
  {
   var entitySet = model.StoreModel.Container.EntitySets.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ElementType == item);
   if (entitySet != null)
   {
    entitySet.Table = entitySet.Table.ToUpper();
   }
  }
 }` Inside, you can modify both `Table` and `Schema` properties of the `entitySet`.